# Protobuff message from Java List<List<Object>>

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I've been trying to package Java List> to a protobuf3 message and I am just wondering what would be the best way to define a proto file that can package such a List and how to map it effectively, since I've been trying and couldn't make it work.

My initial idea:

```
// Proto file
message TutorialAPIResponse {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any values = 1;
}

//Packaging
List<List<Object>> apiValues = Api.getWhatever();
AnalyzeSignalsResponse response = AnalyzeSignalsResponse.newBuilder()
                // line below gives compile error "error: incompatible types: List<List<Object>> cannot be converted to Iterable<? extends Any>"
                .addAllValues(values) 
                .build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really express a doubly-nested list in protobuf; you'd need to express a list of something that itself *has* a list; so.. a `List<Foo>` for some `Foo` that has a `List<Object>`, or in protobuf terms:

```proto
message TutorialAPIResponse {
    repeated Foo items = 1;
}
message Foo {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any values = 1;
}
```

Also, personally I'd avoid the use of `Any`. If you can't express what you're returning without saying `Any`, IMO it isn't a good API surface.

Comment: Totally agreed.